# Android Imageview fill the screen width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

Here my layout file:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#000"
tools:context=".CproductDetails" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_bg"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/product_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_tweet_placeholder_photo_dark_error"
            android:scaleType="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textColor="#95ab56"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="7dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_price"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="#efeeea" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_commerce"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_city"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_township"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dip"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/location_place"
            android:drawablePadding="7dip" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_website"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:autoLink="web"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/location_web_site"
            android:drawablePadding="7dip"
            android:visibility="gone" />

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/product_tel"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/device_access_call"
            android:drawablePadding="7dip"
            android:visibility="gone" />

    </LinearLayout>
```

The result in a phone:

[image]

and the result in a 7in tablet:

[image]

I want to make the image fill the screen width also in tablet. Like Twitter app for example:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your answer is going to depend on your layout, so why don't you post the entire XML layout file?

Comment: android:layout_height="fill_parent"

Comment: **android:layout_width='fill_parent'** will certainly solve your issue, but i think that will distort or rather stretch your image which will not look good. I think the output you are getting now looks pretty OK to me.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Thank you to all but none of your answers solve my problem. Finally I used Maurycy Wojtowicz's [ScaleImageView](https://github.com/maurycyw/StaggeredGridViewDemo/blob/master/src/com/example/staggeredgridviewdemo/views/ScaleImageView.java) class.

> This view will auto determine the width or height by determining if the height or width is set and scale the other dimension depending on the images dimension

Comment: The class manually adds centerInside or centerCrop scaling to the image. It is a bloated version of many better answers on both this and the 10 duplicates of this question that do not require an extraneous class.

Answer (score 68):

Sounds to me like you want to use `android:scaleType="fitCenter"` and `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` on your ImageView.

Answer (score 7):

use `android:scaleType="fitXY"`.

> This will scale the image in X and Y independently, so that src matches dst exactly. This
>   may change the aspect ratio of the src.

Comment: which is relatively useless for most photos, since aspect ratio is critical

Answer (score -3):

android:scaleType="fitXY" .Go for it

Comment: fitXY will take the complete x axis and y axis as our described layout height